# If there was a Code of Professional Conduct or a Code of Ethics, what would it look like?

Tags: rule, professional-practice

If you had a chance to set up a set of rules or a set of guidelines (much in the way as some fields e.g. medicine and engineering share a common Code of Ethics) that you'd wish every person working in the field of sound production (or as well media in general) would have been exposed to and perhaps was even concerned to follow, what would the guidelines/rules be?

Examples:
http://www.nspe.org/Ethics/CodeofEthics/index.html
http://www.socialworkers.org/pubs/code/code.asp
...

Comment: Wheaton's Law belongs in every code of conduct.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not work for free!
2. Do not offer work for little money!
3. If you want workers do not recruit them as trainees!
4. Do not join the loudness war!

:)

Answer (score 0):

5) Don't put sirens or car crash noises in radio commercials.